# Is there an option to pass two parameter in where clause in android to access firestore database

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to write a raw query or pass multiple parameters in android for firestore?

I have tried with

```
`db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("uername", "JHON")`
```

but i can pass only one parameter not multiple. I want to convert the below sample SQL query to firestore query

Example:

```
select * from login where username = "Jhon" and password = "12345"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For raw query you may go with firebase `Query`, here is example

```
Query query = yourCollectionRef.whereEqualTo("username ", "your_value_here")
    .whereEqualTo("password", "your_value_here")
    .whereEqualTo("email", "your_value_here");
```

Another way : you can follow standard approach

Store user data on user Registration in your Firebase database

```
DatabaseReference ref = 

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("credentials");

//to store values in your credentials node just use this code

ref.child("usernames").child(username);
ref.child("usernames").child(username).child("password").setValue(password);

// here username and password are the strings you want to store
```

You can do this with all of your new users to register them in your app. Also this make it easier(read faster) for you to search for the particular username and corresponding password.

You can do so using the following piece of code:

```
ref.child("credentials").orderByChild("usernames").equalTo(username).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // here you can do what you want, like comparing the password of the username and other things you require to do

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```